# With a panel for the user and one for the admin, how can I use $_SESSION for both?

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I have a logout button in both panels, and I have set `SESSION` according to their panels. If I click on the logout button in the admin panel, it will also log me out in the user panel. I have the same code for both the logout buttons.

```
  <?php 

    session_start();
    session_destroy();

    header("location:login.php");
    ?>
```

Comment: use cookies instead session

Comment: set $_SESSION['admin']['username'];  for admin panel and $_SESSION['user']['username'];

Comment: How does your login/logout logic look like?

Comment: session_unset and session_destroy don't accept any parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use unset instead of session_destroy

```
 session_start();

if($_SESSION['admin']){
unset($_SESSION['admin']);
}
elseif($_SESSION['user']){
unset($_SESSION['user']);

}
header("Location:login.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['user']['login'];
    $_SESSION['admin']['login'];
?>
```

If you want to destroy any of them just [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php):

```
unset($_SESSION['user']['login'];)
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE :  session_destroy — Destroys all data registered to a session

so use [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php)

differentiate the user by setting session variable

set session for user

```
$_SESSION['user']['username'];
```

set session fro admin panel

```
 $_SESSION['admin']['username'];
```

you don't destroy the whole session just unset the particular session using unset

```
unset($_SESSION['admin']['username']); // will delete just the name data
```

Answer (score 0):

Use different SESSION key instead.

like $_SESSION['admin'] and $_SESSION['user'];